# Install translation files that should survive updates

Tags: updates, translation

Someone prepared me a `.po` and a `.mo` file for a commercial theme we are using.

How can I install them in such a way that future updates won't destroy them?

Putting them into the `languages` folder was a bad idea. Putting them into the theme folder will make theme updates problematic. I'm thinking of creating a custom plugin that contains the translations. Better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not already using a child theme, build one and place the translations there.

If you are already using a child theme, you can't make a child-of-a-child, so you would need to set up a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can put custom translation files into a site–wide languages folder. It will be `wp-content/languages/themes` by default.